# libgdx trouble rotating 3d model in 2 of 3 axes

Tags: 3d, libgdx, jruby

I'm learning about 3d models and libgdx. I'm trying to rotate my model in 3 axes depending on a keypress. My problem is, I'm able to rotate in one axis but not the other two.

Video of the problematic behavior is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IIVDB0DCWNk&feature=youtu.be

Code is jruby, but should be easy to grok. Here is my model instantiation:

```
def setup_3d_models
  @modelBatch = ModelBatch.new
  jsonReader = UBJsonReader.new
  modelLoader = G3dModelLoader.new(jsonReader)
  model = modelLoader.loadModel(fh('models3d/space_cruiser_4.g3db'))
  $cruiser = ModelInstance.new(model)
end
```

I'm handling the rotation of the model in my inputprocessor for now:

```
class InputMuxer < InputAdapter

  INCREMENT = 15

  def keyDown(keycode)
    puts "keyDown: #{keycode}"
    if $desktop
      case keycode
      when Input::Keys::J
        $cruiser.transform.rotate(1, 0, 0, -INCREMENT);
      when Input::Keys::K
        puts 'pressed K'
        $cruiser.transform.rotate(1, 0, 0, INCREMENT);
      when Input::Keys::U
        puts 'pressed U'
        $cruiser.transform.rotate(1, 0, -INCREMENT, 0);
      when Input::Keys::I
        puts 'pressed I'
        $cruiser.transform.rotate(1, 0, INCREMENT, 0);
      when Input::Keys::N
        puts 'pressed N'
        $cruiser.transform.rotate(1, INCREMENT, 0, 0);
      when Input::Keys::M
        puts 'pressed M'
        $cruiser.transform.rotate(1, -INCREMENT, 0, 0);
      end
    end
```

I also have some code to print visual guides along the three axes. Here is the end result:

[image]
However, I only get rotation across one axis. I'll upload a video shortly with the current behavior.

Any reason why the model.transform.rotate call is messed up? I think I'm misunderstanding the matrix4 geometry.

EDIT: well I am definitely handling the matrix4 incorrectly. No matter what keys I hit, only two of the 16 cells are being modified. That seems baaaaad.

```
def keyDown(keycode)
  puts "keyDown: #{keycode}"
  if $desktop
    print $cruiser.transform
```

---

```
keyDown: 41
[1.0|0.0|0.0|0.0]
[0.0|5.6177378E-6|0.9999998|0.0]
[0.0|-0.9999998|5.6177378E-6|0.0]
[0.0|0.0|0.0|1.0]
pressed M
keyDown: 39
[1.0|0.0|0.0|0.0]
[0.0|5.6177378E-6|0.9999998|0.0]
[0.0|-0.9999998|5.6177378E-6|0.0]
[0.0|0.0|0.0|1.0]
pressed K
keyDown: 39
[1.0|0.0|0.0|0.0]
[0.0|0.25882444|0.9659242|0.0]
[0.0|-0.9659242|0.25882444|0.0]
[0.0|0.0|0.0|1.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Holy schnap fixed it quick!! I was indeed mucking up the matrix4. Instead I needed to pass a vec3 with degrees to Matrix4.rotate:

```
  when Input::Keys::J
    $cruiser.transform.rotate(rotation_vec3(:x), -INCREMENT);
  when Input::Keys::K
    puts 'pressed K'
    $cruiser.transform.rotate(rotation_vec3(:x), INCREMENT);
  when Input::Keys::U
    puts 'pressed U'
    $cruiser.transform.rotate(rotation_vec3(:y), -INCREMENT);
  when Input::Keys::I
    puts 'pressed I'
    $cruiser.transform.rotate(rotation_vec3(:y), INCREMENT);
  when Input::Keys::N
    puts 'pressed N'
    $cruiser.transform.rotate(rotation_vec3(:z), INCREMENT);
  when Input::Keys::M
    puts 'pressed M'
    $cruiser.transform.rotate(rotation_vec3(:z), -INCREMENT);
```

---

```
def rotation_vec3(axis)
    vs = { 
      :x => [1.0,0.0,0.0],
      :y => [0.0,1.0,0.0],
      :z => [0.0,0.0,1.0]
    } 
    Vector3.new(vs[axis].to_java(:float))
  end
```

related libgdx code:
https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Matrix4.html